# Compute the real integral $ \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{2+\sin{\theta}}$ by writing the sine function in terms of the exponential function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I got this problem from my textbook:

[image]

$ \sin{\theta} \mapsto \frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i} = \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2i} $ and $ z := e^{i\theta}$. So $ \frac{dz}{d\theta} = i e^{i\theta} \rightarrow d\theta = -ie^{-i\theta}dz= -i\bar{z}dz.$

What are the limits? Pluggin in $ \theta = 0 \rightarrow z = 1$ which is the same as $ \theta = 2 \pi $?

Comment: You actually get a [contour integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Contour_integrals), typically evaluated with e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

Comment: As your limits are the same, it implies that it is a closed contour integration. So as $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, then $z$ circles around in the complex plane